# Distributing applications using enterprise distribution

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

We have a couple of apps  which allows a user to search for all available properties in specific area, then we have several apps for several different companies that allows the user to search for property that only that company is marketing - i.e you could have apps for Company 1, Company 2, and Company 3 etc which all look the same except for the branding but each one only return results of properties that they are marketing.

I want to distribute these applications using enterprise distribution. I want to upload each company's individual application on company's website so that the respective company may distribute their application to their clients.

Will I require different apple enterprise distribution plan for each company i.e pay $299/ company? or can I use same enterprise plan
Is there any maximum limit of downloads per application I upload using enterprise distribution?
Does apple allows us to do so , as people outside the organization may download application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need Enterprise Distribution if you're distributing within a company (i.e. not via the App Store).

If you want the public to be able to download the app, enterprise distribution is the wrong avenue. Just define multiple apps under your account, upload the different branded versions and set the appropriate Copyright and Support info per version.

Comment: Are you talking about uploading all the versions on appstore through my apple developer account?I think apple minds creating different version of same application, they call it spamming.Please guide me through this

Comment: They don't object if they're genuinely targeted apps. If I have a white labelled app, that I rebrand for a different target client, there is no issue with me uploading each branded app as a different application. Especially given that the data provision between your versions is different.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise licensing is specific to individual companies.  That company has to set up its own license with Apple.  That license can only be used to make and distribute apps to the company's own employees and devices.  They cannot distribute to anyone outside the company with an Enterprise license.

Enterprise does not sound like the solution for what you are trying to do.  Look at Business-to-Business apps if you are looking for some sort of private distribution.